# Adding widget within content

Tags: php, wordpress, genesis

On my Wordpress site using the Genesis framework and magazine pro theme I'm trying to add a widget at the top of the homepage within the content so it's not above the sidebar. I've tried the following:

```
add_action( 'genesis_before_content', 'before_home_top' );
```

gives

```
<div class="content-sidebar-wrap">
<div class="before-home-top">
</div>
<main class="content">
</main>
<aside class="sidebar">
</aside>
</div>
```

Which doesn't work because it goes above both the content AND the sidebar pushing the sidebar down.

```
add_action( 'genesis_after_content', 'before_home_top' );
```

gives

```
<div class="content-sidebar-wrap">
<main class="content">
</main>
<aside class="sidebar">
</aside>
<div class="before-home-top">
</div>
</div>
```

Basically from this image I want the second widget area and not the first full width widget area. https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGDUb.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have access to the Genesis codebase to give you a direct answer, but according to [this page](https://carriedils.com/genesis-hook-reference/) you have some actions available.

**From that page:**

- genesis_before_content_sidebar_wrap
- genesis_before_content
- genesis_before_loop
- genesis_loop
- genesis_after_loop
- genesis_after_content
- genesis_after_content_sidebar_wrap

Give those a try!